# How to disable/rebind Super+` in Ubuntu 17.10 (gnome)?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10

I've tried looking in regular settings, Gnome tweak tool, gsettings list-recursively, but nothing seems to contain this one shortcut (Super+`) that switches between the windows of the same application. I would very much like to rebind that to my own action, but can't seem to do that since the upgrade. Anyone figured this out by any chance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a *Switch windows of an application* binding in standard key bindings menu (*Settings → Devices → Keyboard*), which is 'disabled' by default. So turns out, 'disabled' is not disabled but is `<Super>Grave` and `<Alt>Grave` as its alternative. Set this to any other hotkey and the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was bothering the heck out of me. This works for 18.04 as well. Note for others: If you already had something mapped to ``Super+` ``, you might need to rebind it after doing this.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut (Super+``) is defined in the dconf key `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']`.

You can change or delete the shortcut assignment with dconf-editor (not installed by default), or with the terminal. To remove, for example, the Above_Tab assignment:

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Alt>Above_Tab']"
```

To reset to the default, execute

```
gsettings reset  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group
```

The trick discovered by Alex is nice and very easy, but this gives you full control.

Comment: Your version for removing the shortcut didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04, but this did: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "[]"`.